# Как работает метод contains?

Tags: javascript

1. Метод contains возвращает true если родитель содержит или равен потомку
2. Метод contains возвращает false если родитель не содержит потомка
3. Так будет true

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

console.log(parent.contains(elem));
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="elem"></p>
</div>
```

1. Мы поменяли метод поиска и выводит в консоль ошибку почему ?

```js
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('ada');
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('r');

console.log(post.contains(p))
```

```html
<div id="post_1" class='ada'>
  <p id='p' class='r'>131313</p>
</div>
```

Comment: наверно потому что, возвращают методы разные по типу значения. getElementsByClassName возвращает коллекцию элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором случае Вы получаете массивы элементов.
Соответственно, нужно два вложенных цикла, чтобы проверить, какой из них содержит другой.

В простейшем случае всё вырождается в выборку по индексу 0:

```js
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('ada');
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('r');

console.log(post[0].contains(p[0]))
```

```html
<div id="post_1" class='ada'>
  <p id='p' class='r'>131313</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо (какой-то текст)